# BufferedReader, Socket: How to get BufferedReader to print a multi-line string?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, serversocket

If I make any formatting errors with this question I apologize, this is my first question to stack overflow.

I saw a couple posts similar to what I am looking for but I cannot figure out how to apply it to what I am trying to do.

In short, I am new to socket programming and I want my server to send a string that has multiple lines, the below code isn't what my program is but it gets the point across.

Client.java

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));//server input

System.out.println(in.readLine());
System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

Server.java

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);//output to client

out.println("Hello World! \n");
out.println("This is a printing test! + \n);
```

Again, this is a very shortened version of what I'm trying to do, basically, the client will only print "Hello World!" because the "\n" is considered the next line by the buffered reader. So the second line won't come through.

Obviously I want the client to print "Hello World!" and "This is a printing test!".

I was hoping there was a read() method that was meant for Strings, but I could only see a read() method for int. If I was able to get my point across, could anyone help?

Comment: It looks like both lines end with `\n`.  Try calling `out.flush();` after the println statements.  Sockets have their own memory buffers, so data you send may not actually get sent over the network immediately.  flush() will (usually) force everything that’s been sent to go to its destination.

Comment: @VGR: the `(InputStream, boolean=true)` constructor sets autoflush and println automatically flushes, so you don't need to. See the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

The [`PrintWriter.println(various)` overloads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println()) *add* a line terminator, which varies depending on your platform which you didn't identify. However `BufferedReader` recognizes *any* line terminator, including the one created by `\n` in a string or character literal AND the one added by `println`.

Thus assuming for simplicity you are on some kind of Unix, your code

```
out.println("thing\n");
out.println("other\n");
```

actually outputs *four* lines

```
t h i n g NL   <-- NL in string literal, ends first line
NL   <-- NL added by println, ends second line
o t h e r NL   <-- as above, ends third line
NL   <-- as above, ends fourth line
```

and your client code only reads the first two.

To terminate a line use EITHER `"...\n"` OR `println()` but NOT BOTH.